# reference to a view in an inflated layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-inflate

I have a layout that contains 4 ImageViews with these id's: opp11, opp12, opp13, opp14.
I inflate this layout using:

```
public class FourOptions extends LinearLayout {

public FourOptions(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.par_fouroptions_layout, this);

}
```

I do it like this:

```
fo = new FourOptions(this, null);
l.addView(fo);
```

l is a reference to the layout for which I add the above layout.
this all works fine. 
I now try to add to l another view and to align this view with opp11. I do it like this:

```
    Root result = new Root(this, results[0], results[1], results[2], 45, -1, false); 
    //Root is a class that extends RelativeLayout
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsRoot = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    paramsRoot.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, fo.findViewById(R.id.opp11).getId());
    paramsRoot.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, fo.findViewById(R.id.opp11).getId());
    paramsRoot.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, fo.findViewById(R.id.opp11).getId());
    paramsRoot.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, fo.findViewById(R.id.opp11).getId());
    result.setLayoutParams(paramsRoot);
    l.addView(result);
```

result gets added to the top left corner of the screen as if no layout params were assigned to it.
When I try to align result to views that are in l, the main layout, it works. That leads me to believe that the problem is with 
    fo.findViewById(R.id.opp11).getId()

But I'm not sure.
I have tried a few other ways. All failed.
I'll appreciate suggestions.

This is par_fouroptions_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</View>

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/opp11"
         android:contentDescription="@null"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/rectanglebuttons"
         android:gravity="center" />

 <View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</View>

<ImageView
     android:id ="@+id/opp12"
     android:contentDescription="@null"
     android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height ="wrap_content" 
     android:gravity="center"
     android:src="@drawable/rectanglebuttons"
     />

 <View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</View>

 </LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</View>

<ImageView
     android:id ="@+id/opp13"
     android:contentDescription="@null"
     android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:src="@drawable/rectanglebuttons"
      />

 <View
    android:id="@+id/spaceview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</View>

<ImageView
     android:id ="@+id/opp14"
     android:contentDescription="@null"
     android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:src="@drawable/rectanglebuttons"
      />

 <View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</View>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It may be because R.id.opp11 is inside another parent(FourOptions).

Comment: can you post `par_fouroptions_layout.xml`

Comment: I added par_fouroptions_layout.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review relative layout docs:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

The behavior you are describing is exactly that which would be expected as I read these docs.  I would key in on this line:

> RelativeLayout lets child views specify their position relative to the
>   parent view or to each other (specified by ID). So you can align two
>   elements by right border, or make one below another, centered in the
>   screen, centered left, and so on. By default, all child views are
>   drawn at the top-left of the layout, so you must define the position
>   of each view using the various layout properties available from
>   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.

Instead of adding result to `root`, add it to `fo` and you'll probably see the desired behavior.

Note this isn't a tree spanning description, rather it is "in relation to parent or each other" meaning that you can use params to position the new view either:  In relation to the parent (`root` in your case) or its children (`of`).

Edit:  You've added the xml for your fo layout and I think i see the issue:

You are wrapping op11 and op12 in a linear layout.  In addition to the statements above regarding the parent child or child-child relationships of relative layouts, there is an added issue here.

Namely that what you want to do is ad a view to the wrapper layout which exists in your xml.  You don't have an id on that view, however the block of code in question is:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</View>

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/opp11"
         android:contentDescription="@null"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/rectanglebuttons"
         android:gravity="center" />

 <View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</View>

<ImageView
     android:id ="@+id/opp12"
     android:contentDescription="@null"
     android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height ="wrap_content" 
     android:gravity="center"
     android:src="@drawable/rectanglebuttons"
     />

 <View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</View>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Since this linearLayout is a child of `fo` the above issue applies, however a second issue arises.  Even if you were to add your view directly to this linear layout I think you would still see issues as you're trying to apply RelativeLayout rules to a linear layout.  Change this view to a relative layout, modify accordingly, and then add your results view to this wrapper view and you should see what you want.

Comment: I have tried adding result to fo. Both by fo.addView(result) and by having fo's constructor receiving a Root object and placing it from with in class. Both ways yielded weird results (The images in par_fouroptions_layout.xml appeared smaller or only 2 of the 4 appeared...)

Comment: So i think that relates to your parameters, its going to try and perfectly align your view with the view you're referencing.  They're probably overlapping.

Comment: Also those results aren't really weird at all - you're adding more content to the same sized view.  Either the alloted space needs to increase, or everything is going to shrink to fit in the same space.

Comment: They are not nuts :) It's a way to centralize 2 objects - one to another, Both vertically and horizonatlly.

Comment: But I never got to see result in fo when I tried to add result to fo directly. The images size changed, but result wasn't there...

Comment: Fo is set to wrap_content, but you then try to make it the same size as op11 via aligning sides.  Also par_fouroptions_layout is a linearLayout, not relative.  The params you are applying to root are for locating it within par_fouroptions, but you're using relative layout parameters.  I don't think that works.

Comment: The params centralize the 2 objects, not make them the same size. I use that often. It works nicely. Changing par_fouroptions_layout to  relative layout doesn't solve the problem :(

Comment: You're trying to align all four sides.  Either some of those are being ignored, or its going to mess with the sizes of your views to resolve the discrepancy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68297/discussion-between-maor-yichyeh-and-nathaniel-d-waggoner).